# How could I find the radius of the part of a circle? Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry, radius

[image]

The center of this circle is above the top border of the image. How can I find that center with opencv? Ideas fine too.

Comment: Pl post what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

The [HoughCircles](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles) function would do it. Though you might need to add a border to the image, so that the center coordinates are inside.